# How to call native method and pass callback as a param?

Tags: swift, native

I use a native lib in my project which has such a method

```
...
typedef void(STDCALL * FuncPtr) (const char * str1, const char * str2);
extern FuncPtr DebugLog;

void register_debug_callback(FuncPtr callback);
...
```

when I try to invoke it from my swift code like this

```
func foo() {
 register_debug_callback( what should be passed here? )
}
```

it expects that I pass `FuncPtr`, but how to create it?

Comment: Which C language is the library written in? Add that tag to this question.

Comment: Are the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/swift_standard_library/manual_memory_management/calling_functions_with_pointer_parameters) useful here? Relevant quote: "When calling a function that takes a C function pointer argument, you can pass a top-level Swift function, a closure literal, a closure declared with the @convention(c) attribute, or nil. You can also pass a closure property of a generic type or a generic method as long as no generic type parameters are referenced in the closure’s argument list or body."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a commenter pointed out, you could define a top-level Swift function and pass it as an argument. The function takes `const char *` arguments, which bridge to `UnsafePointer<CChar>` in Swift, so something like this should work:

```swift
func debugCallback(str1: UnsafePointer<CChar>?, str2: UnsafePointer<CChar>?) {
    guard let str1 = str1, let str2 = str2 else { return }

    let swiftStr1 = String(cString: str1)
    let swiftStr2 = String(cString: str2)
    print("str1: \(swiftStr1), str2: \(swiftStr2)")
}
```

Then pass to the function like:

```swift
func foo() {
    register_debug_callback(debugCallback)
}
```

Comment: You’d have to check what the memory handling conventions around those parameters are. You might be responsible for deallocating them yourself.